# How to Flash CS5 AS3 Random Elastic?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web, flash-cs5

I made a photo gallery, every photo start come in with:

```
new Tween(uiLoader,"rotationX",Elastic.easeOut,90,0,4,true);
```

And it's cool but if all photos come in same way, it's little bit tiered to look at it. So I want to ask is here any code to make it random with fade, blinds, iris, fly, Dissolve, Squeeze, Wipe, Zoom, rotationX, Elastic.easeOut???? Here is my code:

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    uiLoader.x =   (back.width - uiLoader.content.width) >> 1;
    uiLoader.y =  (back.height - uiLoader.content.height) >>  1;
    new Tween(uiLoader,"rotationX",Elastic.easeOut,90,0,4,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
var properties:Array = ['rotationX', 'rotationY', 'rotationZ', 'rotation'];
var eases:Array = [Elastic.easeIn, Elastic.easeInOut,
    Elastic.easeOut, Bounce.easeIn, Back.easeOut];

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{

    uiLoader.x =   (back.width - uiLoader.content.width) >> 1;
    uiLoader.y =  (back.height - uiLoader.content.height) >>  1;
    new Tween(mc, getRandom(properties), getRandom(eases), 90, 0, 4, true);
}
function getRandom(array:Array):*
{
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
```

**EDIT :**

I had a look at the doc (I usualy use greensock's tweens). You should to:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

I edited the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this new code, and I past to my gallery, but here is little problem with this code. OUTPUT:
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property fly on fl.containers.UILoader.at fl.transitions::Tween/setPosition()fl.transitions::Tween/set position()
 at fl.transitions::Tween()
 at index_fla::wildlifes_mc_25/completeHandler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at fl.containers::UILoader/passEvent()
 at fl.containers::UILoader/handleComplete()